# Trying to use PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE with the linux prctl syscall

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

In order to use PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE the man page it says that all executable memory areas need to be unmapped. How would one do this without unmapping the area in which the program itself is running and segfaulting?

I think I might be misunderstanding the man page. I tried reading through /proc/self/maps and munmapping all executable regions, but this unsurprisingly segfaulted. Is the man page referring to something else, or am I supposed to be using some other magic to get this to work?